# How to make a data annotations for this rule?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-annotations

I am having a username for users in a project.But there is a rule for selecting the username for users.The rule is this:

> Username can only contain letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes or
>   hyphens and must start with a letter or digit

How to do this with Data Annotations?

Thanks a lot.

By the way the letters can be A-Z and ا-ی.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this using `RegularExpression` as Data Annotation like,

```
[RegularExpression("your regular expression", ErrorMessage = "Enter a valid Username!")]
```

My closest guess in regex for your requirement might be - `"^[a-zA-Z\d\s?(\-')]+$"`
(i'm not sure of the arabic letter!)

Let me know if it helps. Cheers.

Comment: It works.For Persian letters I added this to it:"^[a-zA-Zا-ی\\d\\s?(\\-')]+$".But just one thing.Now the usernames can start with hyphen.I want that they start only with digit or letter.Is there any solution?-Thanks.

Comment: I hope this should do, 
"^[a-zA-Z\d][a-zA-Z\d\s'\-]*$"